# Graph of $\frac{7-3xy^2}{4}$

Tags: calculus, functions

Can someone help on how to solve this question? Do I have to find out the domain..?[image]

Comment: Hint: Can you plug in each value of $x$ into $f(x,y)$ and then match it up? When you do that, there is only a parabola left.

Comment: Would x=-1.2 be D?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%287+-+3+x+y%5E2%29%2F4+for+x+%3D+-1.2, this should help you with all of them and is what I mean by the hint.

Comment: Thank you, that helped lots

Answer (score 1):

Some good and useful news:

- If $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $a>0$ so we have a parabola such that it looks like $$\LARGE{\cup}$$.
- If $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $a<0$ so we have a parabola such that it looks like $$\LARGE{\cap}$$ So for $1$ and $3$ we would have $A$ and $C$. But which one takes these two options? Note that in any parabolas, while we have $ax^2+bx+c$ and $a'x^2+b'x+c'$, the two sides of the parabolas gets wider if  $a<a'$. This means that $A$  and $3$ would be match and $C$ and $1$ are with each other.

Comment: 9Hello Amy. Nice to see here after a semi busy day. Many assignments here are wating for me. :-(

Comment: This is cause of your attention and of course other kind users like Amzoti Thanks a lot. :-)